# Find the absolute maximum and minimum values of f on the set D.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

$f(x, y) = xy^2 + 4$,   $ D$ = {$(x, y)$ | $x ≥ 0,  y ≥ 0, x^2 + y^2 ≤ 3$}

I'm lost on this one. I've tried plugging in critical points but my $D$ ends up being 0, meaning I can conclude nothing about extrema. I've tried Lagrange multipliers and I've gotten nowhere with that. If I were to guess, I'd say the minimum value is 4, but I can't figure out what to try to prove this right.

Comment: Your intuition about the min is correct. Since both $x$ and $y^2$ are non-negative their minimum value is $0$. $4$ is irrelevant

Comment: For the max, just use that $y^2\le 3-x^2$ and then plug in. You will then a function with 1 variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$f(x,y)=xy^2+4\le x(3-x^2)+4=-x^3+3x+4$$ Now for $0\le x\le \sqrt{3}$ you have by differentiating $-x^3+3x+4$ $$-3x^2+3=0 \implies x^2=1 \implies x=1$$ with $(-3x^2+3)'_{x=1}=-6<0$ that it is maximized at $x=1$. So the max is $$x=1, y^2=3-1^2 \implies y=\sqrt{2}$$

---

For the min: $xy^2\ge 0$ in the given domain and $0$ is attained so this is indeed the minimum. Note however that all the points $x=0, y$ are in $argmin$.

Comment: Ah I didn't know it could be converted to a single variable, thanks!